# What does ")x" mean in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure (in MS SQL):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Cuantos INT

IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM IntProgramas WHERE cod_programa IN
        (   SELECT cod_programa FROM IntGrupo_programa WHERE cod_grupo IN
            (   SELECT cod_grupo FROM IntUsuarios WHERE cod_usuario = @cod_usuario
            )
        )
    )
BEGIN
    SET nocount ON

            SELECT P.cod_programa
                     ,nb_programa
                     ,descripcion  
                     ,secuencia
                     ,P.Accion
                     ,P.Controlador
                     INTO #mitabla1 
            FROM IntProgramas P
            WHERE P.cod_programa    
            IN (
                    SELECT cod_programa FROM Intgrupo_programa WHERE cod_grupo IN 
                    (
                    SELECT cod_grupo FROM Intusuarios WHERE cod_usuario=@cod_usuario
                    )
                ) 

            SET nocount ON

            SELECT GP.cod_programa
            ,P.nb_programa
            ,P.descripcion    
            INTO #mitabla2 
            FROM IntGrupo_Programa GP 
            JOIN Intprogramas  P on GP.cod_programa = P.cod_programa
            WHERE GP.cod_grupo IN (SELECT cod_grupo FROM Intusuarios WHERE cod_usuario=@cod_usuario
            SELECT @Cuantos = COUNT(*) 
            FROM( SELECT  nb_programa, descripcion FROM IntProgramas 
            WHERE cod_programa in (select cod_programa from #mitabla1 
            union  select cod_programa from #mitabla2))x

            /*si existe en ambas macheo*/
            SELECT  nb_programa, descripcion, P.cod_programa 
            INTO        #mitabla3 
            FROM        IntProgramas P
            WHERE  cod_programa in (SELECT cod_programa FROM #mitabla1 
            union  SELECT cod_programa FROM #mitabla2) 

            select 
                    t.nb_programa
                  , t.descripcion
                  , t.cod_programa
                  , p.secuencia 
                  , ISNULL(et.cod_menu,0) as cod_menu
                  , ISNULL(et.desc_menu,0) as desc_menu
                  , ISNULL(et_sprog.cod_sub_menu_programa,0) AS cod_sub_menu_programa
                  , ISNULL(et_sprov.desc_sub_menu,0) AS desc_sub_menu_N2
                  , p.Accion
                  , p.Controlador
            from #mitabla3 t 
            JOIN      IntProgramas p
                ON t.cod_programa = p.cod_programa

            LEFT JOIN IntEstructura_sub_menu_programa et_sprog 
                ON t.cod_programa = et_sprog.cod_programa 

            LEFT JOIN IntEstructura_menu_Usuarios et 
                ON et_sprog.cod_menu = et.cod_menu 

            LEFT JOIN IntEstructura_sub_menu_Usuarios et_sprov 
                ON et_sprog.cod_sub_menu_programa = et_sprov.cod_sub_menu

            WHERE et_sprog.cod_programa IS NOT NULL

            order by et.cod_menu, et_sprog.cod_sub_menu_programa, p.secuencia
            --gp.cod_grupo, 

            drop table #mitabla1 
            drop table #mitabla2
            drop table #mitabla3


END
```

i am trying to understand it but when I get to the line

```
union  select cod_programa from #mitabla2))x
```

I don't understand what the x does any help would be apreciated.
I have been trying to run the SP in parts to better understand the flow but that line has really complicated things for me.

Comment: It's not an operator. `.. SELECT (DerivedQuery)x` and `.. SELECT (DerivedQuery) AS x` are equivalent. The `AS` keyword is optional, as is the whitespace.

Comment: It would probably be more obvious if the author of the proc used a more descriptive alias than "x"

Answer (score 5):

X is an alias for this sub-query or derived table:

```
( SELECT  nb_programa, descripcion FROM IntProgramas 
            WHERE cod_programa in (select cod_programa from #mitabla1 
            union  select cod_programa from #mitabla2))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an alias for the subquery:

```
select @Cuantos = COUNT(*)
from (
  select nb_programa, descripcion
  from IntProgramas
  where cod_programa in (
      select cod_programa
      from #mitabla1

      union

      select cod_programa
      from #mitabla2
      )
  ) x
```

When you do `SELECT FROM (SELECT...` you have to name the subquery / derived table.

It works as if you were doing:

```
select @Cuantos = COUNT(*)
    from x
```

Unlike an alias in a table name that is used mostly to make it easier to read or to not have to repeat the table name, in this case an alias is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

X is the alias for the results of the sub-query.  There should really be a space before it though